# What does the "getDeclaredXyz" stands for in Java reflect package

Tags: java, reflection

For instance: `o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` vs. `o.getClass().getFields()`;

Are the "declared" those declared within the current source file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getDeclaredFields()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29):

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private fields, but **excludes inherited fields**. The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order. This method returns an array of length 0 if the class or interface declares no fields, or if this Class object represents a primitive type, an array class, or void.

[`getFields()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29):

> Returns an array containing Field objects reflecting all the accessible public fields of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order. This method returns an array of length 0 if the class or interface has no accessible public fields, or if it represents an array class, a primitive type, or void.
>   Specifically, if this Class object represents a class, this method **returns the public fields of this class and of all its superclasses**. If this Class object represents an interface, this method returns the fields of this interface and of all its superinterfaces.

Comment: Thanks, follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461161/why-am-i-getting-an-emtpy-array-of-annotations-here