# Why am I getting an empty array of annotations here

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

According to the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaredAnnotations%28%29) and to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460980/what-does-the-getdeclaredxyz-stands-for-in-java-reflect-package/6461010#6461010) I should be having "Override" (or something similar) in the following code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
class Test { 
  @Override
  public String toString() { 
    return "";
  }
  public static void main( String ... args ) { 
    for( Method m : Test.class.getDeclaredMethods() ) { 
      out.println( m.getName() + " " + Arrays.toString( m.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
    }
  }
}
```

But, I'm getting an empty array.

```
$ java Test
main []
toString []
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the [`@Override`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) annotation has `Retention=SOURCE`, i.e. it is not compiled into the class files, and is therefore not available at runtime via reflection. It's useful only during compilation.

Comment: I was actually trying with `@Deprecated` and that worked. So, when is `Retention=SOURCE` is recognized for the compiler only?

Comment: @OscarRyz: `@Deprecated` has `Retention=RUNTIME`, and *is* available using reflection. This stuff is all in the javadoc (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html).

Comment: Yes, I could deduce that from your answer. How can I access that information, I guess I could plug in *something* in the compilation phase, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Oscar To find out if a method is overriden, query the superclass through reflection for a method with the same signature.

Comment: @Marcelo, yeap. I'm actually trying to get all the annotations of a given class, either at runtime or during compilation

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this example to help me understand skaffman's answer.

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Foo {
    }

    @Foo
    public static void main(String... args) throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
        final Method mainMethod = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);

        // Prints [@Test.Foo()]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainMethod.getAnnotations()));
    }
}
```